# QGIS Web Client, tiled raster at fixed zoom levels?

Tags: openlayers, qgis-web-client

I have a tiled png raster map, which is available in zoom levels 8, 9 10 and 11, loaded as background layer / basemap via OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.

in `/site/js/Customizations.js` I added in *customBeforeMapInit()*

```
var myBGLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Name","http://<server>/<path>/tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
  {
    isBaseLayer: true
  });

baseLayers.push(myBGLayer);
```

QGIS Web Client only displays this base map when the map window zoom is in one of the available zoom levels. What I'd like is that it maintains map display at the last available zoom level, even when zooming beyond level 8 or 11 i.e. keeping the map in level 8 when zooming to 7 or smaller and keeping it to 11 when zooming to 12 or greater.

Any suggestions how to set this up?